Why is the dimension of projective varities a local property?
I'm trying to understand the proof of Proposition 4.14 in these notes which show that $\dim X = \dim U$ for any projective variety $X$ and any open subeset $\varnothing \ne U \subseteq X$.
In step two, at some point, it is claimed that we can construct a non-constant homogeneous polynomial $f$ that does not vanish on finitely many irreducible varieties. By the projective Nullstellensatz, it amounts to finding $f$ that is not contained in finitely many homogeneous prime ideals.

This sounds like prime avoidance, wouldn't you think?

@KReiser No, it's exactly the other way around. Prime avoidance states that if we have found such an $f$, then it's not in the union of those primes. But I want to know how such $f$ is found.

If by the other way around, you mean the contrapositive, yeah - read the linked answer! You'll have to upgrade the statement a little to the homogeneous case, but it's definitely in one of the standard references (Eisenbud, I want to say? Can't quite remember though).
